# Angular UI Router Loading View, But Not Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm getting very odd behavior from a very simple angular app using ui-router. All the templates are being loaded and displayed properly, but only 1 of the controllers is ever called, the DashboardCtrl. I can't explain this at all.

```
var adminPanel = angular.module('adminPanel', [
  'ui.router',
  'adminPanel.controllers'
])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html',
      controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
    })
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

});

adminPanel.controllers = angular.module('adminPanel.controllers', [])
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $state, AuthService) {

  console.log("hello!"); // never called
  $scope.user = {
    username: null,
    password: null
  };

  $scope.submitLogin = function(loginForm) { 
    // never called
  };

})
.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  console.log("Dashboard"); // this one is called for unkown reason
}])
.controller('HomeCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  console.log("HomeCtrl"); // never called
}]);
```

Markup is super simple:

```
<html>
  <body ng-app="adminPanel">
    <div ui-view></div>
    <script src="js/vendor.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The templates:

dashboard.html

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
```

home.html

```
<h1>Home</h1>
```

login.html

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form name="loginForm" class="login-form" ng-submit="submitLogin(loginForm)">
  <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.username"/>
  <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password"/>
</form>
```

Comment: why you include `js/vendor.js` twice? can you provide plunkr?

Comment: if you on _dashboard_ route, this logically that created controller just for this route.

Comment: That's weird how your Dashboard controller is called even though it doesn't match DashboardCtrl, which is what is stated in the .state(). Are you sure the controller Dashboard isn't being called somewhere else?

Comment: Bad copy pasting. I have updated the code to reflect the actual code.

Comment: @JoelCDoyle, can you provide plunkr? your code seems ok. possibly you just check wrong

Comment: The issue has stopped, but I can't figure out what I changed. I'm still scratching my head.

Comment: or at least provide `dashboard.html`, `home.html`, `login.html`.

Comment: @JoelCDoyle, i think you simple always open `dashboard` so not needed load other controllers

Answer (score 0):

I believe there was an issue with how I was attaching the controllers to the base angular module, but I still can't say for sure.